# Changing location to "worldwide"

Tags: feature-request, jobs, location

Our current Careers Stack Overflow location says *Criteo Europe* but I would like to make it "wordwide" as we do operate from the US, Asia, and Europe. This is to give all our visitors an impression of us truly being global. How can I go about changing from *Europe* to *worldwide/global*?

Link to our current profile: https://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/criteo-europe

Answer (score 3):

Ibrahim,

Thanks for reaching out to us! Changes to your company page can only be made by the owner of it or someone with administrator privileges associated with Criteo's company account on Stack Overflow Careers. That being said, I can definitely look into this change for you all. I'll reach out to the person in charge of your company page and present the suggestion to them.

Enjoy the rest of your day!

Regards,

Stack Overflow Careers,
Customer Success

Comment: If you're really a Stack Exchange employee, you better indicate this in your profile page, in the About Me section. (OK, you're listed in the [Team Page](http://stackexchange.com/about/team) just fine, but still - better have something in the profile as well :))

Comment: @ShadowWizard Noted, and thank you for the tip! As you can probably tell, I'm a bit of a newbie around these parts, so I appreciate the polite nudge.

Comment: From the team page, most SO employees don't have it indicated and have never posted. Some aren't even linked to a profile. It looks like the employees active on the site are mostly developers and community managers.

Comment: @RobertBrown sure thing, cheers! :)